# MYSQL creation and connection

Tags: mysql, windows, visual-studio-code

I cannot either create a database, or connect to one. I've installed the MSSQL extension in vs code, have done all the connection process, but it returns as a connection failed and asks me to retry the process over again.

I've tried changing the names and inputs (localhost, an IP address, master) for the creation of the database, but it will fail to connect.

mssql: Error: Unable to connect using the connection information provided. Retry profile creation?

mssql: Error 2: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Can you connect to that database using another tool?  Try that to validate the authentication info.

Comment: Both MSSQL and MySQL are database **servers**. The extension alone is not sufficient - you need to install the server itself, or get access to one. The extension is just a client, a program to issue commands to the server. Do you have a server?

Comment: I've seen that I can install MYSQL itself, but it never manages to work for me; yes, I have installed it but I can't manage to get it working properly in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL is not the same as MYSQL.  You are trying to connect to mysql with the wrong extension so that is why it isn't working.